# Successful order capture but no email notification PayPal developer sandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have successfully captured orders here:
[image: successful orders]

But aren't getting email notifications here:
[image: no email notifications]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The "Test account email" box is blank and nothing appears? That doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Email notifications aren't particularly interesting anyway. Best to confirm the payment by logging in with the receiver account to [www.sandbox.paypal.com](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com)

Comment: I blanked out the test email box before I posted, and I clicked view all notifications anyway